# Adding data to arrayList Java

Tags: java

So I'm creating a logging program where a user enters the KM's and it saves it etc.

I take in four variables - start KM, end KM, start and end location. I'm new to java so I'm just wondering if anyone can confirm if theres a better way to do this. This is my code so far, I want to save it to an array of sorts (to a list??) so I can access each object i.e. the startKM, but they need to be on the same line, as in object 1 of array etc. and then write to file,

What I was thinking of doing was saving that linked list to a file, and adding a ; in the toString method and when reading the file in just breaking it at the ; Is there a better way to do this?? Thanks guys. the data is assigned from whatever the user enters in the text fields.

```
double startKM;
double endKM;
String startLocation;
String endLocation;


startKM = Double.parseDouble(txtStartKM.getText());
endKM = Double.parseDouble(txtEndKM.getText());

startLocation = txtStartLocation.getText();
endLocation = txtEndLocation.getText();

details.startKM = startKM;
details.endKM = endKM;
details.startLocation = startLocation;
details.endLocation = endLocation;

//List<DrivingDetails> detailsList = new ArrayList<DrivingDetails>();
List detailsList = new ArrayList();

detailsList.add(details);

System.out.println("LinkedList contains = \t " + detailsList.toString());
```

edit: I have another class (DrivingDetails) which holds the following variables:

```
public class DrivingDetails {

   double startKM;
   double endKM;
   String startLocation;
   String endLocation;
}
```

Comment: The details member variables should not be accessed publicly.  You should use setters and getters to modify and retrieve them and they should be private to the class.  Can you post more code?  It isn't clear what we're looking at here...

Comment: Added some more code in, that's all I have

Comment: Do you need the list to be sorted by the startKM? Do you want to save each list element as one ; delimited line in a text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DrivingDetails class violates the principle of encapsulation for object oriented classes.  I would add setters and getters for all properties.  Also, you could create a contstructor that handles initialization for you.

```
public class DrivingDetails {

    private double startKM;
    private double endKM;
    private String startLocation;
    private String endLocation;

    public DrivingDetails(double startKM, double endKM, String startLocation, String endLocation) {
        this.startKM = startKM;
        this.endKM = endKM;
        this.startLocation = startLocation;
        this.endLocation = endLocation;
    }

    public double getStartKM() {
        return startKM;
    }
    public void setStartKM(double startKM) {
        this.startKM = startKM;
    }

    // rest of the methods left for you ...
}
```

Your resulting code would then look like:

```
double startKM;
double endKM;
try {
    startKM = Double.parseDouble(txtStartKM.getText());
    endKM = Double.parseDouble(txtEndKM.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e | NullPointerException e) {
    // the line above assumes java 7
    // recover
}

DrivingDetails details = new DrivingDetails(startKM, endKM,
        txtStartLocation.getText(),
        txtEndLocation.getText());

List<DrivingDetails> detailsList = new ArrayList<DrivingDetails>();
detailsList.add(details);
```

Hope that helps!